# Can I ever get a Schengen visa again after submitting a fake I-20?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, sweden, f1-visas

I'm from India and I applied for a Schengen visa to visit Sweden for a duration of 4 days and since I'm 18 years old, to prove my intent to return home after my visit, the Embassy wanted me to submit supporting documents such as the I-20 issued by my university in the USA. Since I didn't have the I-20 at the time and I didn't want to postpone my trip, **I submitted a fake I-20**.

They granted me a visa but after a few days, called me back to tell me that my I-20 was deemed to have been forged and thus my visa had been annulled. The official reason on the rejection letter listed was "**The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the 
intended stay was not reliable**". The consular official invited me to appeal the decision with genuine documents if I wished to but I've decided to simply cancel my trip for now.

I realize this was an insanely stupid thing to do and in hindsight, I wish I hadn't done it. I have since been issued a valid US F1 visa and also have my genuine I20. If I apply for a Schengen visa again, this time with genuine documents and the US visa stamped to my passport, will I get a visa or will my application be rejected right away?

Comment: Seems to me that it'd be up to the discretion of the person checking the documents. I'd say go for it. Worst that'll happen is that you'll be out the cost of the app fee and you'll get a rejection.

Comment: Now that you have the real US documents, why not appeal and supply them?

Comment: If the time limit for appeal has expired, re-applying may be your best option.

Comment: @Gagravarr: Swedish law states that you have to appeal within 21 days of your visa being rejected/revoked and I received the US documents a little after that so I can submit a fresh application, but I cannot appeal against the rejection.

Comment: @Gagravarr I seriously doubt that he'll be let off on a case of attempted visa fraud that easily...

Comment: @Ranjit Learn this for the future: you **do not** forge docs for a visa application just because **you want** to visit a country **now** and expect no repercussions for it. You just **do not**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The annulment should have been recorded and shared between Schengen countries (there is a database especially for that). This will weight negatively against any Schengen visa application you might submit in the (near?) future. On the other hand, as far as I can tell, you haven't received a formal ban so any consulate can still legally issue a visa if they see fit. It's just that they are going to be particularly careful when evaluating your application.

Actual bans typically have a limited duration and often last for one to three years, at least if you haven't been found guilty of a crime. So even if that would happen, it would still not preclude you from *ever* getting a Schengen visa. But it would obviously make things more difficult.

Comment: Might want to add that since the information is automatically stored and shared among Schengen states, don't even think about not mentioning the previous refusal/revocation if asked - doing so would seriously weigh against you.

Comment: Thanks Relaxed! Is it possible that I'm listed in the SIS database?

Comment: @Ranjit I don't think it's likely (your visa and its annulment should be in the VIS however). [There is a procedure to find out if there is a SIS entry about you.](http://www.datainspektionen.se/in-english/international-co-operation/faq-on-schengen/)